# Is it possible to get the frequency of characters in more then 1 string in Python?

Tags: python

Im aware that we are able to get the frequency of characters in a string by doing this:

```
def freq_of_chars(string):
    all_freq = {}
    for i in string:
        if i in all_freq:
            all_freq[i] += 1
        else:
            all_freq[i] = 1
    print("Count of all characters is: " + str(all_freq)) 
    freq_of_chars('Test')
```

However, if i want to get the frequency of characters in more then 1 string, how do i do it? I tried this but the output shows the  frequency count of each word instead of characters.

```
def freq_of_chars(string1,string2):
    freq = {}
    for i in string1,string2:
        if i in freq:
            freq[i] += 1
        else:
            freq[i] = 1
    print("Count of all characters is: " + str(freq)) 
    freq_of_chars('First','Second')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good opportunity to learn about `*args`. I'll modify your function:

```py
def freq_of_chars(*strings):
    all_strings = "".join(strings)
    all_freq = {}
    for i in all_strings:
        if i in all_freq:
            all_freq[i] += 1
        else:
            all_freq[i] = 1
    print("Count of all characters is: " + str(all_freq))
```

Here, I've turned your parameter `string` into `*strings`, and then added a line which joins all the strings. What `*strings` does as a parameter is allow you to pass *any number of strings* to your function. The `"".join()` simply joins all the strings so that you can iterate over one big string.

Here's an example of how to use the function:

```py
>>> freq_of_chars("hello", "this", "is", "a", "test", "function", "call", "with", "an", "arbitrary", "number", "of", "strings")
Count of all characters is: {'h': 3, 'e': 3, 'l': 4, 'o': 3, 't': 7, 'i': 6, 's': 5, 'a': 5, 'f': 2, 'u': 2, 'n': 5, 'c': 2, 'w': 1, 'r': 5, 'b': 2, 'y': 1, 'm': 1, 'g': 1}
```

Now, it's a bit tedious to have to write all those strings out, so if you happen to *already* have your strings all together in a collection, you can simply unpack that collection in the function call:

```py
>>> strings = ["hello", "this", "is", "a", "test", "function", "call", "with", "an", "arbitrary", "number", "of", "strings"]
>>> freq_of_chars(*strings)
Count of all characters is: {'h': 3, 'e': 3, 'l': 4, 'o': 3, 't': 7, 'i': 6, 's': 5, 'a': 5, 'f': 2, 'u': 2, 'n': 5, 'c': 2, 'w': 1, 'r': 5, 'b': 2, 'y': 1, 'm': 1, 'g': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add them together:

```
def freq_of_chars(string1, string2):
    freq = {}
    for i in string1 + string2:
        if i in freq:
            freq[i] += 1
        else:
            freq[i] = 1
    print("Count of all characters is: " + str(freq))
```

But also you could use:

```
def freq_of_chars(*strings):
    freq = {}
    for i in ''.join(strings):
        if i in freq:
            freq[i] += 1
        else:
            freq[i] = 1
    print("Count of all characters is: " + str(freq))
```

This way you could enter unlimited strings!

Like:

```
freq_of_chars('First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'string', 'infinity!')
```

But I suggest `Counter` from `collections`:

```
from collections import Counter
def freq_of_chars(*strings):
    return Counter(''.join(strings))
```

But why not just:

```
freq_of_chars = lambda *strings: Counter(''.join(strings))
```

Or just no function:

```
freq_of_chars = Counter(''.join(strings))
```

Comment: Dangit, I saw that nobody had added it so I wrote my own answer lol.

Comment: @ddejohn Yah :) `w_buffet` has more UVs...

Comment: should use `itertools.chain` rather than `join` to avoid building another (potentially large) string

Comment: @PCM True, agree

Comment: @TM., I guess it goes too far to depend on `itertools` for this.

Comment: @PCM strongly disagree, if you have large strings or many strings, it's pretty expensive to copy them.  If you really didn't want to use `itertools` you can just iterate over each character with nested for-loops.  Join is shorter but much less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use `freq_of_chars(string1+string2)`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than implementing the logic for counting the chars you could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead

```
from collections import Counter

def freq_of_chars(*strings):
    freq = Counter()
    for string in strings:
        freq.update(string)
    return freq
```

Comment: You do not need a function if you use a collections.Counter. I mean you could just do it directly.

Comment: @PCM True, I was just implementing the same API as the OP